# How to perform a calculation in Power Query based on a group of values in different columns?

Tags: powerquery, m

I have an example table as below:

[image]

I would like to add a calculated column in Power Query as follows:

- for each pair of ID1 and ID2, the calculated column should insert into the respective row the Date of the next Stage Order.
- if any certain pair of ID1 and ID2 has only 1 stage, then calculated Column is blank

I managed to do that in DAX but could not find any solution in M - Power Query.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Expected result as below:
[image]

Comment: Please post sample data as text, not images, so the people trying to help you don't have to retype things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this in powequery, pasted into home..advanced editor..

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID1", "ID2"}, {{"data", each 
    let a= Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
    in Table.AddColumn(a, "OffsetDate", each try a{[Index]+1}[Date] otherwise null)
, type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Stage Order", "Date", "OffsetDate"}, {"Stage Order", "Date", "OffsetDate"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded data",{{"Date", type date}, {"OffsetDate", type date}})
in  #"Changed Type"
```

[image]

It groups, so ID1 and ID2 are together, adds an index, takes the Date from the index of the row below, then expands to get back all the columns. This assumes the data comes in sorted as you want, otherwise do that first

Comment: thanks alot for your help. It was really helpful. Anyways, could you pls explain to me further this snippet that you use:
Table.AddColumn(a, "OffsetDate", each try a{[Index]+1}[Date] otherwise null)
what is the meaning of  "a{[Index]+1}[Date]" ??? why does it behave differently when i change the initial index in the "a= Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type)" ?

Comment: a is the table. a{x} is row x of the table.  a{x}[Date] is the date column in row x. 
  a{[Index]}[Date] would be the date value of the row in the index column.   a{[Index]+1}[Date] would be the date value of the row in the (index  +1) column  If you change the index so that it starts with lets say, five, then the index would always be five away from the current rows position, and you would get the next row as Index+1-5